# Referencing troubles

Tags: java, pointers

I'm writing a program that creates an object which holds to inputs from the user and stores it in an *ArraySortedList*. One of the requirements is to check and see if the particular object is already in the list. The trouble I'm having is whenever I input a secound set of information I get an error.

```
    //Global variables at the top
    ListInterface <Golfer> golfers = new ArraySortedList < Golfer > (20);
    Golfer golfer;

    //Function Variables
    Scanner add = new Scanner(System.in);
    Golfer tempGolfer;
    String name = ".";
    int score;

    while(!name.equals("")) //Continues until you hit enter
    {
        System.out.print("\nGolfer's name (press Enter to end): ");
        name = add.next();
        System.out.print("Golfer's score (press Enter to end): ");
        score = add.nextInt();
        tempGolfer = new Golfer(name,score);

        if(this.golfers.contains(tempGolfer))
            System.out.println("The list already contains this golfer");
        else
        {
            this.golfers.add(this.golfer);
            System.out.println("\nYou added \'Golfer(" + name + "," + score + ")\' to the list!");
        }
    }
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ArrayUnsortedList.find(ArrayUnsortedList.java:67)
at ArrayUnsortedList.contains(ArrayUnsortedList.java:110)
at GolfApp.addGolfer(GolfApp.java:90)
at GolfApp.mainMenu(GolfApp.java:52)
at GolfApp.main(GolfApp.java:24)
```

I'm almost sure it's something to do with how the variable is referenced but I'm not really sure how I could fix it, I have a lot of trouble with variable referencing.

Comment: I would use a SortedSet if you want a sorted set of unique elements.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather use a different ADT but we're forced to work with this one :P. I'll have to check that out though thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your golfer variable is not initalized.
try with :

```
this.golfers.add(tempGolfer);
```

regards.

Comment: Right, you are adding null to the list when you call this.golfers.add(this.golfer), since this.golfer is never assigned.  Now the second time through your code, the NPE comes from the null reference you added to the list on the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I see what I did now. I get tunnel vision when I get stuck on a problem. I have a new problem now which is kind of related. When I try to find out figure out if the list already contains a copy of that element. For instance if I try to enter {Dave,12} and {Dave, 12} twice it won't catch that I entered in the same information with the statement 'if(this.golfers.contains(new Golfer(name,score)))'. I'm thinking it's comparing the addresses of the object to see if they match but is there anyway to use the equals() function (what the contains function uses) to check for repeated data?

Comment: Hi, you should implement the method equals in the Golfer class. It will be called to check if two instances are equal or not.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking he wanted us to do it through the ADT we have to use but I might just do what you said, be a lot simpler. I need to read up on ADT and variable referencing this weekend :P